# * and -* in bash's case structure

Tags: bash, case

```
docase1(){         
    case "$1" in             
        -a )                  
            echo "case a" ;;                
        -b )                    
            echo "case b" ;;                 
        -* )                 
            echo "wrong input" ;;                 
    esac
}
```

We can get the conclusion that `-*` can match -+character(s) instead of character(s).

```
docase1  -g
wrong input
docase1  -gg
wrong input
docase1  g
docase1  gg
```

The fact that commands `docase1  g` and `docase1  gg` get nothing as output means that  -* can  match neither `g` nor `gg`.

```
docase2(){     
    OPTS=$(getopt -o ab    -- "$@");
    if [ $? != 0 ] ; then           
       echo  "wrong" ;     
    fi;     
    eval set -- "$OPTS"; 
    while true; do         
        case "$1" in             
            -a )                  
                echo "case a" ;                 
                shift ;;             
            -b )                    
                echo "case b";                 
                shift ;;             
            -* )                 
                echo "wrong input";                 
                break;;         
        esac    
done
}
```

Why `-*` in docase2  can match character(s)?

```
docase2  g
wrong input
docase2  gg
wrong input
```

Why same expression `-*` result in different effects?
`-*` in docase1 can't match `g` and `gg`,`-*` in docase2 can?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

But that's not what it is being asked to match. The problem has nothing to do with `case` and everything with `getopt` and `set` before it.

Even though your *case* block still checks the same `$1`, it it is no longer getting just your command-line parameter from there. The earlier `set` command *replaced* the original parameters with the output from the *getopt* program, which generally looks like `-- "g"`.

That extra `--` parameter is inserted by *getopt* to indicate that options stop at this point, and non-option arguments begin. That's the entire purpose of *getopt* anyway – to sort and separate the different kinds of command line arguments.

If you add this line, it should become obvious:

```diff
 while true; do
+    echo "arg 1 is '$1'"
     case "$1" in
```